# How can I load the results of a query into a GridView using a ListBox?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get a small block of code working, so that I can click on an item in a ListBox (the field name is 'ReportName') and pull in SQL from a table in SQL Server (the field name is 'SQLScript').  You can see my setup in the screen shots below.  The important thing here is that I want to pull the SQL from the table in SQL Server, into VB, so I can make two small changes to the SQL script, and then pass it into the GridView.  I have to replace two dates in the SQL script, with two dates that I am choosing in VB.  I hope this is clear!

Here is the code that I'm playing around with.

```
Try
        Dim strSql As String = "Select ReportName, SQLScript from Table_1"
        Dim Connstr As String = ""
        Dim SqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim SqlDA As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim DS As DataSet
        With SqlConn
            .Open()
            SqlDA = New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, SqlConn)
            DS = New DataSet
            SqlDA.Fill(DS, "Table_1")
            With Me.ListBox1
                .DisplayMember = "ReportName"
                .ValueMember = "SQLScript"
                .DataSource = DS.Tables("Table_1")
            End With

            DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)

        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    Finally
    End Try
```

This is what I get.

[image]
This is what I want to see.
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be replacing anything. The SQL code should contain parameter placeholders and you can then simply add and set the corresponding parameters. You would handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, get the `SelectedValue`, create a `SqlCommand` with the SQL code, add the parameters, execute the query, load the results into a `DataTable` and bind that to the `DataGridView`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - best make that an actual answer (perhaps provide some code) before someone usurps your efforts.

Comment: @Forty3, I'm not really all that bothered. It's not really complete enough to be an answer as it is and if someone else is prepared to go to the effort to write the code then they're welcome to the spoils. I chose not to write code because I felt that the OP should have been able to get further than they did on their own.